# Play framework: Routing broken

Tags: java, playframework

I am having some issues with the Play framework. It won't compile anymore, giving the following error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable debug
  location: class controllers.Application
```

Indeed this line in Apllication.java is underlined in red in IDEA, but as far as I remember that has always been the case:

[image]

I do have a debug.scala.html file under views. If I change the above return statement to `return ok();` everything compiles fine, but that of course removes all functionality.

PS: The fact that that IDEA thinks that there are errors in the Play code, even when there are none and it all compiles fine, makes debugging somewhat difficult, I find. (As in screenshot above.) Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Do a compile and then idea from play console.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea tries to optimize imports by replacing wildcard imports with dedicated, so you can easily add this import manually:

```
import views.html.debug;
```

TIP: On the other hand try to DO NOT name your view as `debug`, `info` etc. - Play's `Logger` has such methods so if you will write imports carelessly you can accidentally use it in wrong place, so maybe just better call these views like `debugView.scala.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the error: Earlier, I did some refactoring, and IDEA decided to remove the following import from the file, because it thinks it is unused:

```
import views.html.*;
```